# Remove unwanted halo when overlaying transparent PNG using WriteableBitmapEx Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, blit, halo, writeablebitmapex

As seen from the image, the edges of eclipse is not smooth. I am using the following blend mode. Other modes produce more unwanted result.

[image]

```
writeableBmp.Blit(destRect, wbCircle, sourceRect, WriteableBitmapExtensions.BlendMode.Alpha);
```

Attached is the eclipse png. How do I remove the halo around the edges which only visible after the blit operation on Windows Phone?

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't

Comment: To anyone having same problem, try BlendMode.Multiply. It's not the best solution and wont work for everybody.